# Output video stream to a particular screen on dual screen mode - Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: display, raspbian-buster, omxplayer

I am creating a display system for viewing live CCTV footage from my IP Cameras. For this, I am using the omxplayer with the command: `omxplayer --live <my_url>`. This is working fine. However, I have 2 screens set up on my RPi 4 and I want to show the feed for two different cameras on each screen respectively. I tried running the omxplayer command as `omxplayer --display=1 --live <my_url>` and `omxplayer --display=2 --live <my_url>`. However, it still only plays on the screen on which the terminal has been opened.

In the `/boot/config.txt` file I added the following lines:

```
# Enable dual screen mode
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
gpu_mem=128
display_lcd_rotate=0
display_hdmi_rotate=0
```

How do I make it play on a particular screen? I basically want to be able to control which stream goes to which monitor. The monitors have been configured so that it works as an extended display.